# “Access Denied” when accessing a web site

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer, remote-access

I am using Windows Vista IE9. I live outside the US, if it matters.

Recently, I have problem accessing [www.cvs.com](http://www.cvs.com). I always get the message,

Access Denied
You don't have permission to access http://www.cvs.com/ on this server.
Reference #18.b83edc3d.1427525750.3f370291

I have no problem accessing other web sites in the US, such as JCPenny, Walgreen, CNN, etc. I am accessing the web sites from the network provided by local ISP.

The first thing came to my mind was something wrong with my browser. I checked. No problem I can find. I Googled the error. I got the link http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/908356 which basically says I should add the URL of the web to the Trusted site zone. And I did it. Keep getting the same error.

I e-mailed CVS and asked them if they knew anything. They gave me a routine reply. Nothing helpful. I Googled around. Most of the stories I found are about the Access Denied after they did some programming. But, I didn’t do application work on my machine.

I am a regular user of Stack Exchange sites. Naturally, I come here to look for help. If my question is off-topic, please direct me to the right one. If there is a tag missing, please help me to add it. Thanks.

Update (03/09/2021)

I just test it again, instead of getting "Access Denied" message, I am getting the following message

> CVS.com® is not available to customers or patients who are located outside of the United States or U.S. territories. We apologize for any inconvenience.

> For U.S. military personnel permanently assigned or on temporary duty overseas, please call our Customer Service team at 1-800-SHOP CVS (1-800-746-7287) if you need assistance with your order

Thank you for all the help from the users.

Comment: Are you trying to access the site from a network? (your network might be blocking access; typical of gov't/work/school networks but your profile says you're retired, so a long shot).  Can you access the site from another computer or Internet connection (or have friends try)? CVS could be blocking access to some foreign IPs due to the recent bloom of hackings.  BTW, that web site is currently accessible from my computer in the US.

Comment: @fixer1234 I am trying to access CVS from my home computer. The network is provided by local ISP. I have no problem accessing other site such as JCPenny, Walgreen, CNN, etc.

Comment: Try clearing the cache.  It would be interesting to try connecting through one of the services that routes through a foreign network.  If you know someone who uses a different ISP, see if they can access CVS.

Comment: How to clean cache? I actually re-installed IE9 and still no use.

Comment: I can't access it either (from NL). Could just be a misconfigured web server.

Comment: @DavidPostill That's a news to me. I thought it was just me. Can you access JCPenny?

Comment: http://www.jcpenney.com/ loads fine.

Comment: I can't answer this question, but it's probably because the primary language of your browser is not english. CVS.com is known to block requests from browsers with other preferred languages.

Answer (score 2):

In trying to access cvs.com from Ukraine I get the same error message.

**Access Denied. You don't have permission to access "http://www.cvs.com/" on this server. Reference #18**

I cleared my cache, but no dice.   However if I fire up my VPN, and run it through a US server, I have no trouble connecting to cvs.com from Kiev. My guess is that CVS is blocking access from some non-US IP adresses. But the other possibility is that some feature of my local WAN prevents me from connecting. No need to run this down IMHO since the VPN works. Might be better to connect to a pharmacy site via an encrypted tunnel anyway. d:-b

Answer (score 1):

I used to have access to the CVS site from the Netherlands. Now I moved to Spain and I get 'Access denied. With a proxy it works fine of course as I can then simulate that I am back in the USA.
It is clear that it is CVS which is blocking foreign servers not local ISP's.

Answer (score 0):

As user [416E64726577](https://superuser.com/users/401926/416e64726577) mentioned in the comment, CVS blocks access when the browser set the language to Chinese. Since I’m using Firefox, my solution is a [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/zh-TW/firefox/addon/accept-language-per-site/) (open-sourced at [GitHub](https://github.com/sorz/accept-language-per-site)). With that, I set the host as `en-us`.

I’m not aware of a similar extension on Chrome.

#### test the behavior

You can test this if you know how to use the command line. On macOS or Linux this is all you need:

```sh
curl --header 'Accept-Language: zh' --head https://www.cvs.com
```

This gives me “403 Forbidden”. If I replace `zh` with `en` then it’s “200 OK”.

Comment: I think you are wrong. When I asked this question in 2015, I was using a computer that I bought  from Walmart in Florida in the US in 2007. I was using IE. The OS was Windows Vista. The language was English(United States). I was able to access to CVS.com when I was in the US. When I moved to Taiwan in 2009, it was fine. All of a sudden (about a month before I asked this question), I started to have this problem. A year ago, CVS sent me an e-mail and said they refused to deal with customers in Taiwan,

Comment: @scaaahu I might be in a different situation from you; the extension did work for me. Maybe the detection algorithm includes IP address, but language is definitely part of it. (I’m currently in US.)

Comment: NO, language has nothing to do with it. Years after I had this problem, I happened to know an American here, he had the same problem, he told me it's IP address related. He was using a machine from US, too. But, the IP of the ISP tells CVS that the page request was from Taiwan, thus rejected. That was the explanation I was given. I left this question here, hopefully, some one can give me a reasonable explanation. Otherwise, it's discrimination against Taiwan.

Comment: Then how comes the extension fixed it? I don’t think it changed my IP address.

Comment: I just tested it again. I don't have access error anymore. I got this "_CVS.com® is not available to customers or patients who are located outside of the United States or U.S. territories. We apologize for any inconvenience. For U.S. military personnel permanently assigned or on temporary duty overseas, please call our Customer Service team at 1-800-SHOP CVS (1-800-746-7287) if you need assistance with your order_". I did **not** change anything on my browser or computer.

Comment: I tried with cURL and it shows that language makes the difference, at least on my machine. Did you mean that you are able to access CVS even when your browser language was set to Chinese?